# How to store lots of little files

Tags: java, filesystems

I have millions of files which are up to 1MB in size. I need to store them on the file system and be able to read them from within my Java application. I'm a little worried about the cost of the extra metadata, iNodes and performance.

I don't want to have to run an external service for this and want something that is embedded into the JVM.

Before I reinvent the wheel, has this problem already been solved?

I'm imagining that there will be a `FileSystem` implementation somewhere that will store multiple files within one file - but all my googling turned up was Googles in-memory implementation. Added bonus for anything that is asynchronous as the rest of my service is...

Comment: Whats the problem with in memory implementations? And what is the in memory implementation doing - reading the file and appending the text from it in a variable?

Comment: I have heard about zipfilesystem http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html but never work with

Comment: @Prashant - I don't have millions of megabytes of RAM unfortunately.

Comment: I missunderstood that the total file size was 1 MB :D

Comment: Do you have an SSD? If you do you can perform millions of operations per minute.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Sadly - no.

Comment: That sounds like premature optimization to me. Assuming the average file size is 500KB and the block size is 4KB, you would lose less than 1% of storage by just using the file system. But the advantages would be huge: you would have all the file-system utilities and APIs at your disposal to do whatever you need with these files.

Comment: @JBNizet - Doing a `df -i` on my file system, it shows I have a maximum of `983040` iNodes

Comment: If you get a chance "Intel 750 Series 1200 GB PCI Express 3.0 SSD" is around $1000 and can do 420K IOPS, or about 3 seconds to read one million 4 KB files. http://ark.intel.com/products/86741/Intel-SSD-750-Series-1_2TB-2_5in-PCIe-3_0-20nm-MLC

Comment: I'm by no means a file system/hardware expert but, what is the size of your disk?

Comment: I am in no control of the hardware. Its a VM with a 100GB SAN. I am unable to get a dedicated machine either

Comment: Worth noting, that I can get more SAN space which would presumably increase iNodes however, it seems to come too close to the limit for my liking.

Comment: If you have "millions of files" (let's say 2 millions), of size 1MB, you need 2 million MBs, so 2 TB. So you need 20 times the space you currently have. So, either most of the files are much less than 1MB, or you don't actually want to store millions of files, or you need a much larger disk, and I would start by getting the hardware and see how it can be configured and if it matches your expectations before trying to find a software solution that won't solve anything due to the lack of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to store millions of files several times and I always have achieved it storing files under a hierarchy of folders.

File named `abcdefghijk0123.extension` will be stored inside the folder structure `ab/cd/ef/gh/ij/abcdefghijk0123.extension`. Doing it this way you can store lots of files but not all of them in the same folder. Setting up folder structure helps you to handle the max numbers of files for folder.

Comment: Good approach, if files need to stay in filesystem. Very similar to how `terminfo` files typically managed by Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an embedded relational database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) and store the content of the files as a Blob.

I'm not sure if a document-orientated NoSQL database exists, that is embeddable into a Java application. If so, this could be a good solution. You may look at [this article](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10W6-i_Nsl-SZeUq1DDa6hPAh2C0URwWlXtim7Rue3KQ/pub) in order to find a database system, that is suitable for your requirements.

An other solution would be, to store the files simply in the file system and using a caching framework, that holds the files in memory in order to improve performance.